# opening in ruby a modal window with javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby, view, modal-dialog, window

I am creating an application in Ruby. I have created a view for the user in which I have this button :

<%=  link_to 'New message', new_message_path(cosplayer: @cosplayer.id), role: 'button', class: 'btn btn-info', remote: true %>

Linked do it I have this .js code in the js folder:

$(".message").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('shared/message_form')) %>")
$("#newMessage").modal('show')

What happens is that when I run the website and I click on the button 'New Message' the .js file doesn't work and doesn't open the modal window. The page becomes less brighter as the window will appear, but it doesn't work. Is there anything I have to written in order to recognise the js file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can I see the HTML the link_to helper is creating?

Comment: Yes, here it is:      <div id="newMessage" class="modal hide fade">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>

    <h4>A message for <%= @cosplayer.nickname %></h4>
  </div>

Comment: <h4>A message for <%= @cosplayer.nickname %></h4>
  </div>

Comment: <%= form_for(@message)  do |f| %>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="field">
          <%= f.hidden_field :sender, value: current_cosplayer.id %>
          <%= f.hidden_field :recipient, value: @cosplayer.id %>

Comment: <%= f.label :subject %>
          <%= f.text_field :subject, value: @message.subject %>

          <%= f.label :body %>
          <%= f.text_area :body %>
        </div>
      </div>

Comment: Problem solved... Nevermind!